# Haproxy and intermittent 503 issues

Tags: docker, haproxy, boot2docker, http-status-code-503

I am using Haproxy 1.5.14 in a VirtualBox VM (Boot2docker) where assets it loads intermittently show up 503 without any real rhyme or reason, this is especially true on startup of the cluster.

The cluster looks like this, 1 front end with port 80 and 443 to 2 backends servicing static resources and websocket stuff respectively.

Haproxy

- FE (front end, for static resources)
- BE (back end, for websocket connections)

For example the static asset served by the front end might be

https://local.dev.myproject.com/assets/images/back.png

Despite the front end server being up, and nothing has changed, hitting refresh and looking at chrome debugger I will see numerous status 503 or OK 200 304, but it's not determinstic. It can go from 503 to OK to back to 503, on any asset.  When connected to the webserver directly the assets return fine so it seems something with haproxy.

The best I can figure is that the health check isn't working properly and the FE/BE server are being removed temporarily from haproxy's internal roster, but that doesn't makes sense it's checking every half second and I can see the calls haproxy is sending being returned by the FE/BE terminal output window ok, every half second as expected.

If I look at the haproxy statistics report, I can see servers periodically come and go, flickering, despite in the terminal window haproxy is still calling the health checks without gaps and the servers are returning them as expected.

Attached is the current haproxy configuration I'm using, any help is appreciated.

```
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# Example configuration for a possible web application.  See the
# full configuration options online.
#
#   http://haproxy.1wt.eu/download/1.4/doc/configuration.txt
#
#---------------------------------------------------------------------

#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# Global settings
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
global
    # to have these messages end up in /var/log/haproxy.log you will
    # need to:
    #
    # 1) configure syslog to accept network log events.  This is done
    #    by adding the '-r' option to the SYSLOGD_OPTIONS in
    #    /etc/sysconfig/syslog
    #
    # 2) configure local2 events to go to the /var/log/haproxy.log
    #   file. A line like the following can be added to
    #   /etc/sysconfig/syslog
    #
    #    local2.*                       /var/log/haproxy.log
    #
    #log         127.0.0.1 local2
    # log /lnl_zoom_shared/log    local0
    # log /lnl_zoom_shared/log    local1 notice

    chroot      /var/lib/haproxy
    pidfile     /var/run/haproxy.pid
    maxconn     4000
    user        haproxy
    group       haproxy
    daemon
    # SSL
    #ca-base /etc/ssl
    #crt-base /etc/ssl
    ca-base  /myproject_shared/SECURITY/local.dev.myproject.com/
    crt-base  /myproject_shared/SECURITY/local.dev.myproject.com/
    tune.ssl.default-dh-param 1024

    # turn on stats unix socket
    #stats socket /var/lib/haproxy/stats

    # Exposes the stat socket so we can manage the proxy through node.js
    stats socket /tmp/haproxy.sock level admin

#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# common defaults that all the 'listen' and 'backend' sections will
# use if not designated in their block
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
defaults
    mode                    http
    log                     global
    option                  httplog
    option                  http-server-close
    option                  http-pretend-keepalive
    option                  dontlognull
    option                  redispatch
    option                  contstats
    option forwardfor       except 127.0.0.0/8


    retries                 3
    backlog                 10000
    timeout client          25s
    timeout connect         10s
    timeout server          25s
    #long timeoutfor websocket connections
    timeout tunnel          3600s
    timeout http-keep-alive 1s
    timeout http-request    15s
    timeout queue           30s
    timeout tarpit          60s
    default-server inter 3s rise 2 fall 3
    #timeout check           10s

    maxconn                 256

#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# Haproxy's internal stats on the servers below: password protected
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
 stats enable
    stats auth admin:myadminpassword
    stats uri /haproxy
    stats refresh 5s


#---------------------------------------------------------------------
#
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
frontend public
   # HTTP
   bind *:80

     # Redirect all HTTP traffic to HTTPS
       redirect scheme https if !{ ssl_fc }

      # HTTPS
      # Example with CA certificate bundle
      # bind :443 ssl crt cert.pem ca-file bundle.crt
      # Example without CA certification bunch
       bind *:443 ssl crt /myproject_shared/SECURITY/local.dev.myproject.com/local.dev.myproject.com.pem


      acl url_static_BE    path_beg    -i /BE /primus
      use_backend BE          if url_static_BE

      # FRONT END (aka FE) STATIC ASSETS SERVER
      # if path is a static asset, assume the front end server to handle it
      acl url_static    path_beg    -i /static /images /javascript /stylesheets
      acl url_static    path_end    -i .jpg .gif .png .css .js .html .ico
      use_backend FE          if url_static



      # GIT HOOKS for UPDATE on the git repo changes
      acl url_githook       path_beg       -i /gitupdate
      use_backend HACNTL          if url_githook

      #BACK END (aka BE) 



  default_backend BE




#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# controller for haproxy
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
backend HACNTL
   # Tell the backend that this is a secure connection,
   # even though it's getting plain HTTP.
   option forwardfor
   http-request add-header X-Forwarded-Proto https if { ssl_fc }

    server      SELF 127.0.0.1:3300

#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# static backend for serving up images, stylesheets and such
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
backend FE
   # Tell the backend that this is a secure connection,
   # even though it's getting plain HTTP.
   option forwardfor
   http-request add-header X-Forwarded-Proto https if { ssl_fc }
   option httpchk GET /haproxy/getstatus
   option httpchk HEAD /
   balance     roundrobin

   #server      FE1 11.22.33.44:8000  maxconn 256
     server FE_172.17.0.2  172.17.0.2:8000 maxconn 256 check inter 500ms

#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# round robin balancing between the various backends
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
backend BE
  # Tell the backend that this is a secure connection,
  # even though it's getting plain HTTP.
  option forwardfor
  http-request add-header X-Forwarded-Proto https if { ssl_fc }
  #http-request set-header X-Custom-Header %[url]
  #http-request set-header Connection upgrade
  #http-request set-header Upgrade websocket
  option httpchk GET /haproxy/getstatus
  cookie SRVNAME insert nocache
  balance     roundrobin


     server BE_172.17.0.3 172.17.0.3:8888 maxconn 256 cookie       BE_172.17.0.3 check inter 500ms
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

while not a absolute fix, allowing each server to start one at a time has fixed the issue for now.  basically adding a sleep between docker run command

Comment: I have the same situation, haproxy->docker nginx with uwsgi app and very often I got 503 when the page is refreshed. Could you elaborate on your solution, what do you mean "allowing each server to start one at a time" ?

Comment: @ksirg  there's a couple different 503 issues, same error that come from different sources.   My application has several docker containers for the web service (e.g. 1) database, 2) front end servers 3) haproxy to loadbalance) that when I started them all at once, would result in immediate 503 errors on startup.      Starting them one at a time with a couple seconds delay between them reduced the 503 on startup, but on refresh, at other times they still come up for reasons I don't understand.  But it I think is networking related.